# Route matching snapped to end of road

Tags: here-api

Using the heremaps routing api, the response includes snapped route-links to the end of the road or to the next junction however a vehicle may have stopped before that. I'd like to have the snap finish exactly at the last coordinate if possible?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the different WaypointParameterTaypes: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html

In general will the Router consider only points matched to the street network. E.g. if your endpoint is located on some private area with no street network connection the Routing service can just consider the closest route-able location. 
But you could work around with a poyline from the last destination to your end position and attach this to your displayed route.